# Как изменить текст в метках Яндекс.Карт? Как измерить расстояние между точками?

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-maps-api

Сделал карту, на которой прокладывается маршрут от точки А до точки Б.

```
function init () {
    /**
     * Создаем мультимаршрут.
     * Первым аргументом передаем модель либо объект описания модели.
     * Вторым аргументом передаем опции отображения мультимаршрута.
     * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.MultiRoute.xml
     * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.MultiRouteModel.xml
     */
    var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
        // Описание опорных точек мультимаршрута.
        referencePoints: [
            "Алматы, Наурызбай батыра д13",
            "Астана, Гейдара Алиева 11"
        ],
        // Параметры маршрутизации.
        params: {
            // Ограничение на максимальное количество маршрутов, возвращаемое маршрутизатором.
            results: 2
        }
    }, {
        // Автоматически устанавливать границы карты так, чтобы маршрут был виден целиком.
        boundsAutoApply: true
    });
    console.log(multiRoute.properties);
    // Создаем карту с добавленными на нее кнопками.
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.750625, 37.626],
        zoom: 7
    }, {
        buttonMaxWidth: 300
    });
    // Добавляем мультимаршрут на карту.
    myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
}  
ymaps.ready(init);
</script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Карта рисуется, но все же есть два вопроса:

1. Как сделать так, чтобы текст в метках был свой, а не тот, что он ставит по умолчанию?
2. Как узнать расстояние от точки А до точки Б?

Comment: [метка](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/dg/tasks/how-to-add-placemark-docpage/#how-to-create-custom-marker-icon) , [еще метка](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/) ,  [расстояние](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/ICoordSystem-docpage/). Оно?

Comment: Метка используется стандартная, а мне надо получить доступ к меткам  multiRoute так как он прокладывает маршрут, так же и с расстроянием